# Could anybody explain basketball terms on points?

Tags: meaning-in-context

He was raggedy as...
Went two for 15. Seven points.

He finished with 16 points on six of 14.

'Went two for 15'
'six of 14'

I guess it's about points but I can't really understand what they mean.
Please explain what those numbers mean.

Comment: You should try asking on https://sports.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Omegastick Although this is a sportsball question, sports phrasing and idioms frequently carry over to other areas of life, particularly in uniquely competitive fields like law and sales.I'd say this question is appropriate to remain here.

Answer (score 1):

The writer is discussing successes versus attempts. There are three different constructions:

1. to go X for Y
2. X of Y
3. to be X and Y

Number 1 and Number 2 are mostly for scoring/goal attempts. If he "went 2 for 15", he attempted to score 15 times, but he only got points for 2 of those attempts.

Number 3 is usually for win/loss records. I coach a team, and we're currently at **2 and 3** for the season. That is, we've won 2 matches and lost 3 matches (5 total) so far.

A specific exception to #3 is in American football: If the announcer says something like  "It's **1st and 10** for the Jaguars",  that means the Jaguars need to advance the ball 10 yards down the field to earn a 'first down.'

((Sorry, don't have a reference to link for you.))